# How to remove duplicate ID rows. While removing, use the rows that has NULL value in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

While removing duplicate rows with same ID value, how to remove the rows that has null value in one particular column.

Note: there are other non-duplicate rows (below e.g., 12) that has NULL value and should still get selected in the result set.

Input table:

```
Id  | sale_date  | price
-----------------------------
11   20051020     22.1  
11   NULL         20.1  
12   NULL         20.1  
13   20051020     20.1
```

Expected result:

```
Id  | sale_date | price
-----------------------------
11  20051020    22.1    
12  NULL        20.1    
13  20051020    20.1
```

Comment: What happens if you have duplicate `Id` values, but with different `sale_date` values that are not null.  What do you expect to get in that case?

Comment: I would prefer the one with latest date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have SQL Server 2008 or above, this will work for you. I use row_number and assign the values by ID starting at the max date. So any value higher than 1 is lower than the max date for that particular ID so I delete row_num greater than 1.

Check it out:

```
DECLARE @yourTable TABLE (ID INT,Sale_date DATE, Price FLOAT);

INSERT INTO @yourTable
VALUES  (11,'20051020',22.1),
        (11,NULL,20.1),
        (12,NULL,20.1),
        (13,'20051020',20.1);

WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY sale_date DESC) AS row_num
    FROM @yourTable
)

DELETE
FROM CTE
WHERE row_num > 1

SELECT *
FROM @yourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT *  FROM (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Sale_Date desc) AS ROW_NUM FROM AA1)  A
WHERE ROW_NUM<2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have duplicate Ids, and not every sale_date is NULL, you can keep the latest date, and delete the other ones:

```
DELETE @MyTable 
FROM @MyTable AS T1
INNER JOIN (SELECT Id, MAX(sale_date) AS sale_date FROM @MyTable GROUP BY Id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) 
    AS T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID AND (T1.sale_date is null OR T1.sale_date < T2.sale_date)
```